# How to provide tab space for ansible variables

Tags: ansible

I have a task and i am writing the task result to the file. While writing to the file I need to give indentation.
I have tried the below command but it is indenting only the first line of the variable. But, I need the entire lines in the variable need to be indent. Is there anyway to do that?

```yaml
  - name: task
    shell: some command
    register: result

  - shell: 'echo -e \\t{{result.stdout | to_json}} >>file.txt'
```

Comment: If your `result` has `stdout_lines`, you can iterate over that.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in @Seshadri comment, your `shell` output lines are available either globally in `stdout` or in a list containing one element for each line in `stdout_lines`.

You can use the latest to treat each line separately. You don't really have to loop in this case. There are functions to apply the same filter to each element of a list. The following should do the trick to add a tab to each line element:

```
result.stdout_lines | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\\t\\g<1>')
```

You simply have to join the resulting list with new lines to get your content as expected.

You should use the existing tools in ansible when they exist rather than using shell whenever possible. One reason is that modules will very often handle idempotence for you (e.g. write the file only when content actually changed). In this case, the [`copy` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) using the [`content` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html#parameter-content) (rather than [`src`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html#parameter-src)) is probably the best solution. So your final solution would look like:

```yaml
- name: Write my result file
  copy:
    dest: file.txt
    content: "{{ result.stdout_lines
      | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\\t\\g<1>') | join('\n') }}"
```